# dynamic linq multiple vs single .where query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Why does the single where query give a different result than multiple where queries ?

```
query.Where("666 = ID");
query.Where("ActiveFrom < @0 && ActiveTo > @1 && ValidFrom < DateTime.Now && ValidTo > DateTime.Now", toDate, fromDate);
```

`query.ToString();` results in :

```
SELECT  *
    FROM [Country] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 666 = [Extent1].[ID]
```

and the same query with multiple where calls

```
query = query.Where("ActiveFrom < @0", toDate);
query = query.Where("ActiveTo > @0", fromDate);
query = query.Where("ValidFrom < DateTime.Now");
query = query.Where("ValidTo > DateTime.Now");
```

results in :

```
SELECT  *
FROM [Country] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (666 = [Extent1].[ID]) AND 
([Extent1].[ActiveFrom] < convert(datetime2, '2016-10-23 11:40:35.9538054', 121)) AND 
([Extent1].[ActiveTo] > convert(datetime2, '2016-06-23 11:40:35.9518052', 121)) AND
([Extent1].[ValidFrom] < (SysDateTime())) AND 
([Extent1].[ValidTo] > (SysDateTime()))
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a stupid question but by the code you posted... in the first example - did you set query = "first where" and then again for the second where?

Comment: `query.Where("666 = ID");` doesn't do anything because you're not assigning this query to a variable whereas your second example does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the different `Where`s to be relevant you need to assign them back to `query`:

```
//instead of:
query.Where("666 = ID");
query.Where("ActiveFrom < @0 && ActiveTo > @1 && ValidFrom < DateTime.Now && ValidTo > DateTime.Now", toDate, fromDate);

//do:
query = query.Where("666 = ID");
query = query.Where("ActiveFrom < @0 && ActiveTo > @1 && ValidFrom < DateTime.Now && ValidTo > DateTime.Now", toDate, fromDate);
```

Also the `Where` calls can be chained. Most linq extension methods return `IEnumerable<TSource>` and therefore can be chained.

Applying the chaining on your second query it will look like this:

```
query = query.Where("ActiveFrom < @0", toDate)
             .Where("ActiveTo > @0", fromDate)
             .Where("ValidFrom < DateTime.Now")
             .Where("ValidTo > DateTime.Now");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the calls dont modify the query, they return a new instance representing the modified query instead. Thus the second example results in the big query whereas the first results in a simple where condition only.